# Kiel traduki la anglan idiotismon "sea legs"

Tags: single-word-requests

Kiam oni uzas la anglan idiotismon "sea legs" oni signifas la kapablon vojaĝi per ŝipo sen suferi marmalsanon. Ekzemple, "After a few more days on board you'll get your sea legs" ("post kelkaj pliaj tagoj surŝipe, vi ne plu marmalsanos.")

Mi supozas ke la plimulto de esperantistoj (aparte tiuj kiuj ne parolas la anglan) ne komprenus la kunmetitan vorton "markruroj". "Maraj kruroj" ne multe superis ĝin.

Ĉu iu povas proponi pli bonan alternativan tradukon?

Answer (score 1):

Mi uzus, por tiu ideo, *alkutimiĝi*

```
post kelkaj pliaj tagoj surŝipe, vi alkutimiĝos
```

Fine de tiu konstruo, se vi volas, vi povas precizigi la alkutimiĝon: *al la maro / ŝipo / vento*.

Answer (score 0):

Ĉiuj lingvoj havas esprimojn, kiujn oni ne facile povas traduki en aliaj lingvoj. Tiam oni havas du alternativojn

- klarigi la fenomenon per jam ekzistaj esprimoj
- inventi novan vorton kaj ekuzi ĝin por priskribi la fenomenon

Kompreneble la unua alternativo estas preferinda. Vi mem jam uzis tre bonan esprimon "vi ne plu marmalsanos". Eble humore oni povas diri, ke "vi estas martaŭga".